# Can bad memory hardware slow down Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, task-manager, memory-management

My Windows 10 is sluggish on a 24GB laptop with an SSD. Often I click on an option in an app and it takes 2-5 seconds to respond. I went through disabling Windows Search and some unneeded Windows services and I disabled Cortana. There's no virus scanning going on. Looking at the Task manager the CPU and RAM look OK and are usually less than 50% with occasionally 100% spikes. I decided to check the machine's memory. I used Memtest64 and Windows own memory diagnostic tool and both showed they encountered memory errors. Also one time Windows Blue Screened and it mentioned Memory Management was the failure reason. However, I don't get any app crashes.

My question is.. can bad memory slow down Windows performance and if yes, why? I would expect an app crashing randomly which doesn't happen so I was wondering does Windows know where the bad memory parts are it avoids using them? Does it do extra work doing some kind of fault tolerance so apps don't get affected? I am just hypothesizing.

This is my work laptop so I am planning to have IT replace the memory modules if possible or get a new laptop, but I still wanted to know if bad memory has negative effects on Windows performance.

Comment: bad memory or memory incompatibility. If you build your own pc and you add different brand memories with different timings etc, you may see similar results.

Comment: Do the memory test app test for memory incompatibility? I ran the diagnostics app twice but both times it didn't write the results in the event log. Just one time I saw it reported errors while running. The modules are from two vendors with the same speed.

Comment: No. Memory incompatibility means that the memory sticks works together and as a user you don't notice any problem at first, but due to the timings, weird glitches occur that look like random faults.

Comment: I am specifically asking about if it affects Windows performance. The performance which affects me every day all day long. I don't care about Windows faults. It happened once only so it's not a problem.

Comment: my point is, that it can affect windows in weird ways.